# config.active_record.default_timezone = :local ... Doesn't seem to have any effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

The configuration for active_record.default_timezone does not seem to work as advertised.  I expected that after setting:

```
 config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

(in config/application.rb) that a time retrieved from the db would be converted to the local timezone, i.e. it would show the same offset, e.g. "+0200", as a local time.

> **config.active_record.default_timezone** determines whether to use
>   Time.local (if set to :local) or Time.utc (if set to :utc) when
>   pulling dates and times from the database...
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

```
2.0.0p247 :016 > user = User.new name: "Tom", email: "tom@gmail.com"
 => #<User id: nil, name: "Tom", email: "tom@gmail.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 

2.0.0p247 :017 > user.save   
(0.3ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Sun, 08 Sep 2013 23:38:22 UTC +00:00], ["email", "tom@gmail.com"], ["name", "Tom"], ["updated_at", Sun, 08 Sep 2013 23:38:22 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.7ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 => true 

2.0.0p247 :018 > puts user.created_at
2013-09-08 23:38:22 UTC  <----------+  WHY IS THIS THE SAME TIME AS IN THE DB...
 => nil                             |             
                                    |
2.0.0p247 :019 > Time.now           |
=> 2013-09-08 17:38:36 +0200 <------+  ...WHEN THE LOCAL OFFSET IS +0200???

2.0.0p247 :020 > Rails.application.config.active_record.default_timezone
 => :local 

2.0.0p247 :021 > 
2.0.0p247 :022 >   Rails.application.config
 => #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000100af1508 @root=#<Pathname:/Users/7stud/rails_projects/test_postgres>, @generators=#<Rails::Configuration::Generators:0x00000100ff3128 @aliases={}, @options={:rails=>{:orm=>:active_record, :test_framework=>:rspec, :integration_tool=>:rspec, :stylesheet_engine=>:scss, :javascript_engine=>:coffee, :scaffold_controller=>:jbuilder_scaffold_controller, :json_template_engine=>:jbuilder}, :active_record=>{:migration=>true, :timestamps=>true}, :test_unit=>{:fixture=>true, :fixture_replacement=>nil}}, @fallbacks={}, @templates=[], @colorize_logging=true, @hidden_namespaces=["sass"]>, @encoding="utf-8", @allow_concurrency=nil, @consider_all_requests_local=true, @filter_parameters=[:password], @filter_redirect=[], @helpers_paths=["/Users/7stud/rails_projects/test_postgres/app/helpers"], @serve_static_assets=true, @static_cache_control=nil, @force_ssl=false, @ssl_options={}, @session_store=:cookie_store, @session_options={:key=>"_test_postgres_session", :cookie_only=>true}, @time_zone="UTC", @beginning_of_week=:monday, @log_level=:debug, @middleware=#<ActionDispatch::MiddlewareStack:0x00000100fa5158 @middlewares=[ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Lock, #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x00000102a2e6c8>, Rack::Runtime, Rack::MethodOverride, ActionDispatch::RequestId, Rails::Rack::Logger, ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions, ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions, ActionDispatch::RemoteIp, ActionDispatch::Reloader, ActionDispatch::Callbacks, ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending, ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement, ActiveRecord::QueryCache, ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, ActionDispatch::Flash, ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, Rack::Head, Rack::ConditionalGet, Rack::ETag]>, @cache_store=[:file_store, "/Users/7stud/rails_projects/test_postgres/tmp/cache/"], @railties_order=[:all], @relative_url_root=nil, @reload_classes_only_on_change=true, @file_watcher=ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker, @exceptions_app=nil, @autoflush_log=true, @log_formatter=#<ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter:0x00000100af8c18 @datetime_format=nil>, @eager_load=false, @secret_token=nil, @secret_key_base="123f640f8d665d9a20bc49ae045b1a0edd41972db82091ec8bd3ff0836d805698fbe70ca75d2a78c3cd088774412b67f789d74b7a2422ad30acc589487f49ce7", @assets={:enabled=>true, :paths=>[], :precompile=>[#<Proc:0x00000100b02970@/Users/7stud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:54>, /(?:\/|\\|\A)application\.(css|js)$/], :prefix=>"/assets", :version=>"1.0", :debug=>false, :compile=>true, :digest=>false, :cache_store=>[:file_store, "/Users/7stud/rails_projects/test_postgres/tmp/cache/assets/development/"], :js_compressor=>nil, :css_compressor=>nil, :initialize_on_precompile=>true, :logger=>nil}, @paths=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 @current=nil, @path=#<Pathname:/Users/7stud/rails_projects/test_postgres>, @root={"app"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b1b2e0 @paths=["app"], @current="app", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob="*", @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=true, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "app/assets"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b1aef8 @paths=["app/assets"], @current="app/assets", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob="*", @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "app/controllers"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b1ac50 @paths=["app/controllers"], @current="app/controllers", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=true, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "app/helpers"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b1a840 @paths=["app/helpers"], @current="app/helpers", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=true, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "app/models"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b1a110 @paths=["app/models"], @current="app/models", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=true, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "app/mailers"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b19da0 @paths=["app/mailers"], @current="app/mailers", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=true, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "app/views"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b19940 @paths=["app/views"], @current="app/views", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "app/controllers/concerns"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b193a0 @paths=["app/controllers/concerns"], @current="app/controllers/concerns", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=true, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "app/models/concerns"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b19058 @paths=["app/models/concerns"], @current="app/models/concerns", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=true, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "lib"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b18978 @paths=["lib"], @current="lib", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=true>, "lib/assets"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b181a8 @paths=["lib/assets"], @current="lib/assets", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob="*", @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "lib/tasks"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b238a0 @paths=["lib/tasks"], @current="lib/tasks", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob="**/*.rake", @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "config"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b22f90 @paths=["config"], @current="config", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "config/environments"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b22090 @paths=["config/environments"], @current="config/environments", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob="development.rb", @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "config/initializers"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b21bb8 @paths=["config/initializers"], @current="config/initializers", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob="**/*.rb", @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "config/locales"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b212a8 @paths=["config/locales"], @current="config/locales", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob="*.{rb,yml}", @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "config/routes.rb"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b20d58 @paths=["config/routes.rb"], @current="config/routes.rb", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "db"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b20858 @paths=["db"], @current="db", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "db/migrate"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b20510 @paths=["db/migrate"], @current="db/migrate", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "db/seeds.rb"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b20088 @paths=["db/seeds.rb"], @current="db/seeds.rb", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "vendor"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b2bf78 @paths=["vendor"], @current="vendor", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=true>, "vendor/assets"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b2b8e8 @paths=["vendor/assets"], @current="vendor/assets", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob="*", @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "config/database"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b2b320 @paths=["config/database.yml"], @current="config/database", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "config/environment"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b2add0 @paths=["config/environment.rb"], @current="config/environment", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "lib/templates"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b2a1c8 @paths=["lib/templates"], @current="lib/templates", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "log"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b29f70 @paths=["log/development.log"], @current="log", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "public"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b299a8 @paths=["public"], @current="public", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "public/javascripts"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b29390 @paths=["public/javascripts"], @current="public/javascripts", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "public/stylesheets"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b28af8 @paths=["public/stylesheets"], @current="public/stylesheets", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>, "tmp"=>#<Rails::Paths::Path:0x00000100b28418 @paths=["tmp"], @current="tmp", @root=#<Rails::Paths::Root:0x00000100b1b6a0 ...>, @glob=nil, @autoload_once=false, @eager_load=false, @autoload=false, @load_path=false>}>, @autoload_paths=[], @eager_load_paths=["/Users/7stud/rails_projects/test_postgres/app/assets", "/Users/7stud/rails_projects/test_postgres/app/controllers", "/Users/7stud/rails_projects/test_postgres/app/helpers", "/Users/7stud/rails_projects/test_postgres/app/mailers", "/Users/7stud/rails_projects/test_postgres/app/models", "/Users/7stud/rails_projects/test_postgres/app/controllers/concerns", "/Users/7stud/rails_projects/test_postgres/app/models/concerns"], @autoload_once_paths=[], @cache_classes=false>
```

I also got the same results in my rails app when I displayed the created_at time in a view.

config/application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module TestPostgres
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Athens'
    config.active_record.default_timezone = :local


    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order for `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local` to return a localized time, you need to explicitly declare a default timezone:

```
# config/application.rb
config.time_zone = 'Singapore'
```

Subsequently, Rails `DateTime` objects will be returned from ActiveRecord in localized time:

```
User.last.created_at
#=> Mon, 09 Sep 2013 09:09:43 SGT +08:00 

Time.now
#=> 2013-09-09 09:11:48 +08:00
```

Comment: It looks like it should be config.time_zone, and in any case it has no effect.  I get the same results as before.  I exited rails console, put the line `config.time_zone = 'Singapore'` before the line `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local`, and I still get:  `2.0.0p247 :007 > user.created_at
 => Mon, 09 Sep 2013 02:09:49 UTC +00:00` after the INSERT: `INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Mon, 09 Sep 2013 02:09:49 UTC +00:00], ["email", "t@gmail.com"], ["name", "Tom"], ...`

Comment: Well, I tried exiting rails console again, and now it's working.  The INSERT now looks like this: `INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Mon, 09 Sep 2013 10:18:46 SGT +08:00], ["email", "t@gmail.com"], ["name", "Tom"], ["updated_at", Mon, 09 Sep 2013 10:18:46 SGT +08:00]]`, but I notice once again that `config.active_record.default_timezone` does not work as advertised.  The Singapore time is saved in the db, rather than a UTC time.

Comment: ...with retrievals from the db causing rails to convert what's stored in the db to Singapore time.

Comment: Whoops.  Not true.  That INSERT is followed by:   `(0.2ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 => #<User id: 16, name: "Tom", email: "t@gmail.com", created_at: "2013-09-09 02:25:31", updated_at: "2013-09-09 02:25:31">`.  And if you compare times, the time displayed in that message as been adjusted to UTC time.

Comment: The `TimeWithZone` object returned from `object.created_at` is adjusted to your specified local time, correct? Can you clarify whether you are still experiencing any ill effects?

Comment: No it's working as I expect now.  For future searchers, please change config.timezone to config.time_zone.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Another hitch: if I comment out `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local`, so that I have just `config.time_zone = 'Singapore'`, then times are converted from Singapore to UTC before being saved to the db, and times are converted from UTC to Singapore when times are retrieved from the db.  So it doesn't look like `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local` does anything.  Then if I set `config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc` along with `config.time_zone = 'Singapore'`, there is no change: times retrieved from the db are converted to Singapore time.

Comment: So I am still wondering what the heck `config.active_record.default_timezone` does?

Comment: It seems as though there's some inconsistency in the invocation of `default_timezone`. For instance, see [this Github issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6816) for the Rails core that was opened over a year ago... it looks as though it's still unresolved. It sounds like the issues you're witnessing _may_ be database related. Perhaps a detailed read can evince a few clues as to what's going on.

Comment: More information here at [lighthouseapp](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5324-configtime_zone-not-setting-default_timezone-for-ar-causing-errors-with-postgres).

Answer (score 11):

Be careful here. `config.time_zone = "Kuala Lumpur"` sets the time zone at the application level.

`config.active_record.default_timezone = :local` causes records from ActiveRecord to return something like `2000-01-01 00:00:00 +0800`

`config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc` (default) causes records from ActiveRecord to return something like `2000-01-01 00:00:00 UTC` for the exact same instance as the above.

I think it is recommended that `:local` is not used because values written to the DB should be read as UTC. Setting `:local` would read datetime/time values from the DB as a particular timezone.

Note that `Time.now` is system level time, since it is a Ruby method. `config.time_zone` has no bearing on the value returned by `Time.now`. In the answer above, the user's computer happened to share the same time zone as the application.

More reading: http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/

Comment: is not created_at saved as utc format in side db, so why do we need to set it as defalut_timezone?